# Moving from WinForms c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I am writing a game in WinForms, using c#. Well, I absolutely love Visual Studio and WinForms, because coding is very simple, and there is usually no need in any additional content.
The game is text based, but it is also heavily based on UI. But, WinForms has no transparency, and this is something that hurts alot. Interface, labels and pictures are created and positioned dynamically.

I thought about moving to WPF, but I do not know, if i will be able to place controls dynamically in WPF like in WinForms (because WPF is based on grids).

Should I learn more about WPF, or there is any simple WinForms-like analogs, that support transparency and will allow me to create text-based games with UI?

P.S here is image, its QSP game (not mine, but it is something that I want to achieve, but have improved UI, transparent images, and etc.)
[image]

Comment: FWIW, I don't think you'll have any trouble at all replicating this game screen using WPF.

Comment: as far as i can see winforms supports transparency - google it

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error thanks for reply. Still, my UI is a bit different. Is it possible to add something dynamically to WPF, and place all the stuff and buttons in the point X.Y without any trouble, even if it is happening on the grid?

Comment: @pm100 thanks for comment. As far as I know, there is now way to get normal tranparency in WinForms without very big efforts. And it will heavy overload your application with code. BTW, quoting MSDN: "
Windows Forms controls do not support true transparency. The background of a transparent Windows Forms control is painted by its parent". Here is article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @HeideKnight: Though I can't answer your specific question with the level of detail you give, I think you'll find that WPF is a _lot_ more flexible in virtually every aspect than Windows Forms.

Comment: _"WPF is based on grids"_, well no you can plonk things where you want like in WinForms too.   In my experience WinForms supports _some_ level of transparency but generally it is with much pain and effort compared to WPF which does it 100% out of the box with no effort.  As you are making a **game** you may be interested to know that WPF is **hardware accelerated** via DirectX unlike WinForms.  Of course depending on the type of game, hardware acceleration is not a requirement.  I've seen quite a few good WinForms games

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, well, good to know, thanks.

Comment: @Micky, thanks for reply. How can I place things where I like? I have tried, but is it possible without grid, like in WinForms, when you just type `this.Controls.Add["Name"]`?

Comment: @HeideKnight Easy my friend, just create a new `UserControl`, the root will be a `LayoutRoot` by default (or you can create a new `Window`, it does not matter).  Then just drag and drop controls into the design surface.  You will note that as you do so the `Margin` is auto-populated depending on where you place the control.  It is the `Margin` that allows you to reposition controls where you like.  Highly recommend using _Blend_ - a WPF/Silverlight visual designer -  which is part of Visual Studio rather than using VS itself. Blend can do a few things VS can't.

Comment: @Micky, thanks for help, mate! Looks like its time to try move my code to WPF.

Comment: @HeideKnight Any time.  Anything to help a fellow game programmer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a multi-part question, I will not attempt to address any one specific question but rather provide resources to allow you to embark on learning WPF on your own, and assure you that moving to WPF is a safe choice for converting your application.

> I thought about moving to WPF, but I do not know, if i will be able to place controls dynamically in WPF like in WinForms (because WPF is based on grids).

Yes, you can [generate](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/12/08/dynamically-generating-controls-in-wpf-and-silverlight), [create](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19112/Dynamic-User-Interfaces-in-WPF), and [position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514519(v=vs.90).aspx) content dynamically in WPF. See links for example code.

> Should I learn more about WPF

Yes, you should [learn more](http://www.wpftutorial.net/) about [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx).

> or is there any simple WinForms-like analogs, that support transparency and will allow me to create text-based games with UI?

Yes, you can create [transparent windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2008/09/08/transparent-windows-in-wpf.aspx) and [transparent controls](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8296361a-6261-4b3d-b72d-95d8de0eb3b8/setting-the-opacity-of-a-xaml-control-to-see-through-it?forum=wpf) in WPF.

I hope these resources are useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and sharing these useful resources, friend!